# C++ Make explicit that library owns pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, ownership

Through the use of smart pointers or not.  I'd like to make it explicit to the user of a library that all pointers they pass into the library should now be owned by the library (ie. not released by the user).

Many open source libraries just state it in their documentation that the library owns everything or does not.  They discuss expected life time of pointers being passed in.  Surely there is a more strict way to convey this information to the user.

An example would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: how are these instances (that pointers point to) created in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want that then you should provide methods in the library to also create these objects, instead of having users allocate them. It doesn't make sense that the library releases the object it has not created, as it can not guarantee that they both use same allocation facility.

There is an option that the library creates these objects, wrapped in a custom smart pointer which hides the pointer and doesn't allow external client to release the wrapped objects, but it is always possible to circumvent the guards. In my experience, trying to be too smart always backfires: things get more complicated, but the developer using the library can always outsmart it.

IMO, the safest approach is a simple lifecycle management API (e.g. CreateObject, DestroyObject) and clear and concise documentation. Then the user is free to choose how to handle the lifetime (e.g. `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` with `DestroyObject` as custom deleter, or something completely different).

Answer (score 2):

Use an owning smart pointer in all your classes, that will take ownership (ie will destroy the object once done with it) and any pointers passed from the users will be taken over by this owning smart pointer.

A good example is `std::unique_ptr`, once things are done, will destroy it's object.

If you need custom destruction, you can pass it a custom deleter.

Even better is of course to have both creation (ie through `make_unique`) in your classes too, as you will then have RAII, which will avoid all leaks.

Comment: But he didn't say that the user won't be able to keep a pointer to the data they give to the library to own. I think `shared_ptr` would be better no?

Comment: @SethCarnegie yes, if the user still wants to keep hold of the pointer too, then indeed a `shared_ptr` is the correct solution.

Comment: @SethCarnegie `std::unique_ptr<T, D>` is convertible to `std::shared_ptr<T>`. There is no reason to return an `std::shared_ptr` if you can return an `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @LucDanton I got the impression he was giving things _to_ the library, not taking them from the library (that is, passing arguments, not returning values).

Answer (score 0):

If you write your library functions, methods and constructors to take `std::unique_ptr<T>` by value, then there will be no way for the user to release the pointer themselves as their `unique_ptr` instances will be cleared on move-copy of the arguments.

```
class C;
void library_function(std::unique_ptr<C> by_value);

void user_code() {
    std::unique_ptr<C> user_c{std::make_unique<C>("param", 5)};
    library_function(user_c);
    assert(user_c.get() == nullptr);
}
```

If the user should be able to continue to observe the object, then you could accept `shared_ptr` on the interface, or you could provide observer methods that return a raw (non-owning) pointer or (better) a reference.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to [overload the new/delete](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html) operators, and use those functions to filter access.  For example, new might create the object, then store the address into some private static data structure.  Delete could be designed so that it blocks any attempt to use the `delete object` idiom, unless certain conditions are met.